# Handling function parameters with blueprints

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I have this method:

```
def extract_and_segmentate(input_folder, input_folder):

    extract_txt_from_pdf(input_folder, output_folder)
    extract_txt_from_pptx(input_folder, output_folder)
    segmentate(output_folder, output_folder, 35)
```

And I want to wrap it inside a blueprint like:

```
@extraction.route('/extract', methods=['GET'])
def extract_and_segmentate()
```

I know that usually methods in blueprints don't have parameters, so how can I handle my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.args.get('query_parameter')`

```py
extraction = Blueprint('extraction', __name__)

@extraction.route('/extract', methods=['GET'])
def extract_and_segmentate():
    input_folder = request.args.get('input_folder')  # assuming input_folder is passed as a query parameter
    output_folder = request.args.get('output_folder')  # assuming output_folder is passed as a query parameter

    extract_txt_from_pdf(input_folder, output_folder)
    extract_txt_from_pptx(input_folder, output_folder)
    segmentate(output_folder, output_folder, 35)
```